# Javascript confirm, capturing the user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a piece of third-party add-on implemented into a website that prompts the user to confirm before deleting.

```
confirmDelete: function (event) {
    var go_ahead = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this draft? This action cannot be undone.");
    if (go_ahead) {
        return;
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

In my own js file, I want to find out if the user clicked "Cancel" or "OK".

I can tell when the user is prompted with the confirm window (by them clicking the delete button), but I am unable to figure out if the user clicked Cancel or OK.

I want to keep this code separate as the add-on gets updated regularly.

```
$('button[name="delete"]').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('delete btn clicked');
    console.log(event);
});
```

I went thru the contents of the event in my console but nothing stuck out at me.

Comment: I don't understand; `confirm` returns `true` or `false` (explicitly) based on OK/Cancel buttons. I'm not sure you can attach jQuery events to native browser dialogs.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not sure either, but I wanted to get some feedback on whatever is possible. I am not against directly going into the confirmDelete and modifying it to accomplish it.

Comment: Oh, you just want the true/false in your `onClick` handler?! Return the results of calling `confirm`? I think I'm missing what you're saying.

Comment: @DaveNewton I want to know if they clicked OK or Cancel in the confirm window that is triggered from a different js file.

Comment: Which file the code is in is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the value of calling `confirm` to your `onClick` handler, e.g.,

```
var SomeObject = {
  confirmDelete: function () {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this draft? This action cannot be undone.");
  }
};
```

Then:

```
$('button[name="delete"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var confirmed = SomeObject.confirmDelete();
    if (!confirmed) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // etc...
});
```

I removed event twiddling from the confirmation function. This keeps it close to the actual event, and seems more canonical jQuery. It improves readability and simplifies testing.

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this without modifying the first block of code (confirmDelete) in my question.

Comment: @Brad You can't return a value without returning a value. (You could fire an event for yet another layer of obfuscation if returning something would mess up existing code.) If you want to do something based on knowing what happened in the `confirm` call you're going to have to modify that function.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I just wanted to find out if I could do this without modifying that function. I will go ahead and modify it. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, as far as I know, if you're using native widgets, you're kind of out of luck. You could use a non-native widget/dialog, though (which gives you a lot more flexibility anyway).

Answer (score 1):

### Another Alternative

The selected answer will not work if the widget assigns an event listener to the button. And this seems very likely based on the code provided. It will instead display two confirmation dialogs, which is quite confusing.

As a workaround, OP might override the window confirm method. The replacement method could intercept both the message and the result. And while I wouldn't advocate overriding native methods, it is a pragmatic solution that I've used successfully with legacy systems.

**Run the snippet to try**

```js
var confirm2 = window.confirm;

window.confirm = function(message) {

  var result = confirm2(message);

  debug.innerHTML += 'confirm: ' + message + '\nresult = ' + result + '\n';

  return result;

}


// Simulate 3rd Party Widget
var widget = (function() {

  var methods = {
    confirmDelete: function(event) {
      var go_ahead = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this draft? This action cannot be undone.");
      if (go_ahead) {
        return;
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementsByName('delete')[0].addEventListener('click', methods.confirmDelete);

  return methods;

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button name="delete">Delete</button>
<xmp id="debug"></xmp>
```